# Any In-place Javascript Rich Text Editor available?

Tags: javascript, jquery, text-editor

Are there any in-place editor in JS that supports Rich Text like TinyMCE / FCKEditor?

e.g. of in-place editing (non-rich text): http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable/default.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[jEditable](http://www.appelsiini.net/2008/5/jeditable-and-tinymce) and [TinyMCE](http://sam.curren.ws/index.cfm/2008/6/12/jEditable-TinyMCE-Plugin) together:

[Google](http://www.google.com.au/search?q=jeditable+tinymce&sourceid=navclient-ff&ie=UTF-8&rlz=1B3GGGL_enAU216AU217&aq=t) is your friend!

Comment: This answer is a great example of why answers should contain more than just links. Both your links were broken now; I found a replacement for the first, but not the second.

Answer (score 2):

[NicEdit](http://www.nicedit.com/) is what you want I think, there are some demos available on the website.

Comment: And it does a good job. Unfortunately the resulting markup is far from valid xhtml since nicedit uses the editmode of the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just use TinyMCE (/whatever), size it smaller, attach some jQuery event handlers to the text and replace it with the editor when appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

I would use FCKEditor.

Answer (score 0):

There is jWYSIWYG: http://projects.bundleweb.com.ar/jWYSIWYG/