# Using best_in_place with rich-text editor like TinyMCE

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jeditable, edit-in-place, best-in-place, rich-text-editor

I'm using the `best_in_place` gem to do in-place editing in a Rails application. However, I need (X)HTML editing on some of the text areas, so I need a rich-text editor. TinyMCE is being used elsewhere on the site.

However, it's not trivial to add an editor to `best_in_place`. To grossly oversimplify, the gem uses jQuery to insert the `textarea` tag on the fly, and TinyMCE initializes at page load, replacing available `textarea`s with an editor, so when `best_in_place` puts in its `textarea`, TinyMCE has already come and gone. I've tried re-initializing TinyMCE after `best_in_place` inserts its textarea, but I don't think I've found the correct place(s) in the code to do that, because so far it hasn't worked.

There's [a rumor](http://railscasts.com/episodes/302-in-place-editing?view=comments#comment_154834) that this integration is possible, but no documentation was visible in my web searches, so pointers are welcome. (Likewise [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/452762/306084) is unhelpful, pointing to two broken links.) I think my preferred order of solutions would be something like

- Here's how to integrate TinyMCE with `best_in_place`
- It can't be done with TinyMCE but here's how to do it with another rich-text editor
- It can't be done with `best_in_place` but here's [another rich-text edit-in-place solution](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_in_place_editing) for Rails 3.2.x.

Answer (score 1):

I gave up trying to do this with `best_in_place`, so this question as written is still open to a better answer. However, for those who might find this question later and wonder what I eventually came up with, here's what I did in the end:

1. Junked `best_in_place`.
2. Forked [the jeditable-rails plugin](https://github.com/afeld/jeditable-rails) to
   get [Jeditable](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable) as an in-place editor.
3. [Adapted the plugin](https://github.com/pjmorse/jeditable-wysiwyg-rails) to provide Jeditable, [jWYSIWYG](https://github.com/akzhan/jwysiwyg), and the Jeditable-jWYSIWYG custom input as assets for the Rails asset pipeline (along with related CSS and images for jWYSIWYG).
4. Profit! (Not really.)

Anyway, if you're trying to do rich-text in-place editing in Rails 3.2, try the [jeditable-wysiwyg-rails](https://github.com/pjmorse/jeditable-wysiwyg-rails) plugin. It's providing the assets for the [markItUp editor](http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/home/) as well, although because I'm not using it I'm not sure they're all there and/or arranged properly.

Comment: There's an editor called Froala with built in best_in_place like functionality and integration with rails.