# textarea not editable in Chrome or Webkit nightly, editable in Safari, Firefox and Opera

Tags: google-chrome, webkit, textarea, jeditable, jwysiwyg

I'm using [Jeditable](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable) and [jWYSIWYG](https://github.com/jwysiwyg/jwysiwyg) (via [my own jerry-rigged Rails engine](https://github.com/pjmorse/jeditable-wysiwyg-rails)) to provide [in-place WYSIWYG editing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13076653/306084) in an application. Recently I've had reports that the HTML mode in the WYSIWYG editor (that is, when we can see and manipulate the actual HTML being generated) is not editable in Chrome (>27 - it works in 26). It works in Safari (tested 6.0.5, 8536.30.1), Firefox (tested 19 and 21) and Opera, all four on Macs. (Let's not speak of IE.) I pulled a Webkit nightly (r151773) and that also shows the problem, suggesting this is a Webkit problem.

This setup works by building both a standard `textarea` with the HTML, and an iframe with the WYSIWYG content. When we open or close HTML mode, one is hidden (`display:none`) and the other is shown, depending on which way we're going. It's just that in Chrome, one can't change the content in the `textarea`. Can't get the cursor in it, can't select text, can't change the contents in the developer tools (?!?) just can't do anything with it.

What could be causing this in Chrome but not Safari, FF or Opera? What should I be looking for in terms of attributes on `textarea` which might be causing this?

ETA: It looks like this is a bug in Chromium, Webkit, or both. (I opened [this Webkit bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=117888), then found [this jWYSIWYG issue](https://github.com/jwysiwyg/jwysiwyg/issues/364) which references [a Chromium bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=246738).) The jWYSIWYG issue suggests a workaround (adding a browser test for Chrome) but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: This is a Webkit bug. It has been [fixed in Chromium](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=246738) but as of this writing is [still open in Webkit][2]. [2]: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=117666